# any decentralize trading platform？

Tags: erc-20

i am thinking about convert eth to btc etc,is there any platform for this? Uniswap can only convert among erc20 tokens but I am thinking about converting among different type of token?

Answer (score 2):

Eth and Btc are not tokens, they are full-fledged blockchain coins: Eth is the native asset (coin) in Ethereum blockchain and Btc is the native asset in Bitcoin blockchain.

To truly exchange an asset from one blockchain to another requires currently some centralized entity: some entity has to guarantee the trust between the blockchains. Typically this is a centralized exchange. Other alternatives are various bridge projects, such as wBTC, which is a ERC20 token in Ethereum blockchain - you deposit real BTC and you get equal amount of wBTC (wrapped BTC) tokens you can use in the Ethereum blockchain. But this kind of wrapped asset is also distributed in a centralized fashion.

So, the answer is basically no, you can't trade BTC to ETH without a centralized authority.